# Viewing video stream from a network camera

Tags: html, google-chrome, ffmpeg, gstreamer, mpeg

I have placed the below code in a webpage and viewed over my local webserver

```
<img src="http://192.168.1.117/Streaming/channels/1/httpPreview" alt="Cam1 feed">
```

The stream is configured to output mpeg and not RTSP

This works without issues when viewed on a windows computer with chrome & firefox and is OK when viewed on my Android phone with Chrome.
But this does not work when viewed on a iphone or ipad with either Chrome or Safari.

After searching for a while I am coming to the conclusion to try and encode into a WebRTC to add to a video tag.

Is this the right approach as it was fairly easy to get working on a computer and android phone.

Comment: I would think feeds should be in a video tag

Comment: The feed unfortunately doesnt work in the video tag. 

Im looking for advice specifically on displaying a stream from an IP Camera to a webpage in Chrome on a Ithing (iphone/ipad)